# Updating SQL with TextArea - only updates with short strings

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a textarea in a form. That form, upon submit, inserts some information into the databse. Even though "newsText" is a longtext, I am only able to insert short strings. I will update this question with the exact amount of characters.

The form:

```
<form id="newsForm" action="<?php echo $uploadHandler ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"> 
    <div class="managementNewsTitle">
        Title<br />
        <input id="inputNewsTitle" name="inputNewsTitle" type="text"></input>
    </div>

    <div class="managementNewsTitle">
        Image<br />
        <input id="inputNewsFile" type="file" name="file" onchange="document.getElementById('inputNewsFilename').value = value;"><br />
        Name<br />
        <input id="inputNewsFilename" type="text"></input>
    </div>

    <div class="managementNewsTitle">
        Text<br />
        <textarea id="inputNewsText" name="inputNewsText"></textarea> 
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" name="givenFileName" id="givenFileName" value=""> 
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="<?php echo $max_file_size; ?>"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="newsSubmitValue" id="submitValue" value="no">
    <input type="button" id="newsSubmitButton" onclick="newsSubmit()" name="submitButton" value="Save"></input>

</form>
```

The INSERT:

```
if($_POST['newsSubmitValue'] === "yes") {
    $newsTitle = $_POST['inputNewsTitle'];
    $newsText = $_POST['inputNewsText'];
    $newsImageURL = $_POST['givenFileName'];


    mysql_query("INSERT INTO cs_news VALUES (DEFAULT, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '".$newsTitle."', '".$newsText."', 'Images/".$newsImageURL."')");
}
```

Comment: Best not to put 'solved' in question titles. I've edited it out here as it's seen as bad practice on SO.

Comment: I wanted to show that this problem was solved, since I cannot accept my answer as THE answer yet. 48 hours is just too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved. It was not the amount of characters, but the TYPE of characters.

I used quotes in the string. Which made my SQL statement end prematurely.

Woops.

Comment: You really need to escape your inputs

Comment: @Amal Murali, I sure as probably want, but I can accept it in 8 hours from now. It takes 2 days to be able to accept your own answer.

Comment: @Dave, yup, that was the solution.

Comment: @StefanSchouten do you want me to post it as the answer for you tick ?

Comment: I posted the answer + additional information you may consider whilst your ahead :)

Answer (score 0):

Theres a few things i should mention:

You need to escape your inputs to the query using this php function:

`mysql_escape_string()`

```
if($_POST['newsSubmitValue'] === "yes") {
    $newsTitle = mysql_escape_string($_POST['inputNewsTitle']);
    $newsText = mysql_escape_string($_POST['inputNewsText']);
    $newsImageURL = mysql_escape_string($_POST['givenFileName']);


    mysql_query("INSERT INTO cs_news VALUES (DEFAULT, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '".$newsTitle."', '".$newsText."', 'Images/".$newsImageURL."')");
}
```

Also you are using `mysql_*` which i do not recommend. You should consider using `mysqli_*` or perhaps `pdo`. The benefit of `pdo` is that, it will escape strings automatically so you don't have to worry about it. This in turn makes things more secure without the mistake of forgetting to escape something. (Human error)

Heres two you can chose from:

[MYSQLi_*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

[PDO MYSQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)

**Reason i suggest the change can be read here:**

[MYSQL deprecated in 5.5.0](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php)